# Why are .domain, tickFormat and tickValues not recognised inside dimensions variable? (d3, parallel coordinates)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I am creating a parallel coordinates plot using d3.js, but am struggling to format axis labeling as I would like.

For instance, one of my axes, 'Buffer Concentration', is plotted on a log scale, which I've specified through the dimensions variable, like so.

```
var dimensions = [
  ...
  {
    key: "b.Conc",
    description: "Buffer Concentration",
    type: types["Number"],
    scale: d3.scale.log().domain([.1, 100]).range([innerHeight, 0]),
    tickValues: [.1,.2,.4,.6,.8,1,2,4,6,8,10,20,40,60],
    tickFormat: d3.format(4,d3.format(",d"))
  },
  ...
];
```

However, as you can see from the resulting plot below, my attempt to specify which tick labels are shown (through `tickValues`) and that they be shown as ordinary numbers rather than powers of 10 (through `tickFormat`) are not working. Additionally, the axis does not span the domain I specified in `scale`; it should be [0.1, 100], not [0.1, 60].

Why is this?

[image: Section of Parallel Coordinates Plot]

## Code

The data.csv, index.html and style.css files for my plot can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/LThorburn/5f2ce7d9328496b5f4c123affee8672f). When opening locally, it [only] works in Firefox.

Thanks in advance for any help, and apologies if I'm missing something basic - I'm new to d3.

Comment: Could you please provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to apply custom ticks and tick values to generated scales in this line: https://gist.github.com/LThorburn/5f2ce7d9328496b5f4c123affee8672f#file-index-html-L189

Not sure, but smth like this should help.

```
    if (d.tickValues) {
      renderAxis.tickValues(d.tickValues);
    }

    if (d.tickFormat) {
      renderAxis.tickFormat(d.tickFormat);
    }
```